# Airmon-ng command not found

Tags: 12.04, command-line, aircrack-ng

In the terminal I get `Command not found` when I type:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

What can I do to access the `airmon-ng` command?

Comment: Did you read the man-page of airmon-ng beforehand ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get [THIS](http://ubuntu2.cica.es/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng_1.1-4_i386.deb) package and open that with Software center to install . Then you're done .

Then try with `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`
 it will be fine . Just now i tested myself.

Answer (score 12):

Install the `aircrack` package first, then you will be able to use the `airmon-ng` command.

#### Here's how

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

You may now use the command.

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Comment: `E: Package 'aircrack-ng' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 2):

Just try `sudo airmon-ng` in a terminal. It should work for you as worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try with:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install aircrack-ng
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate what do you mean@

Comment: sudo:aptitude:command not found

Comment: Do you have the `aircrack-ng` package installed? If not, you should install it to be able to run one of its commands. Copy-paste the two above commands in a terminal (one at time) and see what happens. (You could also copy-paste here the output of the second command)

Comment: when i run the first line of the given command it says sudo:aptitude:command not found.

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen an Ubuntu without `aptitude` preinstalled. However, you can try to replace `aptitude` with `apt-get` and write here what happens.

Comment: @Avio: For the last year or two, aptitude has not been installed by default. Instead, one should recgive instructions using `apt-get`, which *is* installed by default.